How to create data frame from rvest scraped website, preserving nested structure of data
Say that I use read_html_live() from the rvest package to pull some code that looks like this:
books <- minimal_html('
  <div>
    <div class="book">
      <div class="booktitle">Book 1</div>
      <div class="year">1999</div>
      <div class="author">Author 1</div>
      <div class="author">Author 2</div>
      <div class="author">Author 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="book">
      <div class="booktitle">Book 2</div>
      <div class="year">2022</div>
      <div class="author">Author 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="book">
      <div class="booktitle">Book 3</div>
      <div class="year">1845</div>
      <div class="author">Author 5</div>
      <div class="author">Author 6</div>
      <div class="author">Author 7</div>
      <div class="author">Author 8</div>
    </div>    
  </div>')

I would like to use the rvest package to create a data frame (or tibble would also be fine) with the information contained above. I would like it to be organized at the author level, so each row will contain an author, the booktitle, and the year.
If I only cared about the first author, it would be easy. Something like:
data0 <- books %>% html_elements(".book")
title <- data0 %>% html_element(".booktitle") %>% html_text2()
year <- data0 %>% html_element(".year") %>% html_text2()
author1 <- data0 %>% html_element("author") %>% html_text2()
data <- data.frame(title, year, author1)

However, I would actually like to extract all authors, the authors being "children" within book. And the dataframe would now have eight rows, one for each author. For instance, row 8 would have Book 3, 1845, and Author 8. How can I do this?
Here is a rough idea, but I am looking for easier solutions:
data0 <- books %>% html_elements(".book") 
title <- data0 %>% html_element(".booktitle") %>% html_text2()
year <- data0 %>% html_element(".year") %>% html_text2()

authors <- data0 %>% html_element(".author")

And then loop over the three elements of authors and save each of them to a dataframe. And then associate each of these author dataframes with the relevant title and year and somehow transform it to be a long data frame.

Here is one approach which uses lapply to loop over the book nodes:
library(rvest)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
books <- minimal_html('
  <div>
    <div class="book">
      <div class="booktitle">Book 1</div>
      <div class="year">1999</div>
      <div class="author">Author 1</div>
      <div class="author">Author 2</div>
      <div class="author">Author 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="book">
      <div class="booktitle">Book 2</div>
      <div class="year">2022</div>
      <div class="author">Author 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="book">
      <div class="booktitle">Book 3</div>
      <div class="year">1845</div>
      <div class="author">Author 5</div>
      <div class="author">Author 6</div>
      <div class="author">Author 7</div>
      <div class="author">Author 8</div>
    </div>
  </div>')

data0 <- books %>%
  html_elements(".book") |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    tibble(
      title = x |> html_element(".booktitle") |> html_text2(),
      year = x |> html_element(".year") |> html_text2(),
      authors = x |> html_elements(".author") |> html_text2(),
    )
  }) |>
  bind_rows()

data0
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>   title  year  authors 
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>   
#> 1 Book 1 1999  Author 1
#> 2 Book 1 1999  Author 2
#> 3 Book 1 1999  Author 3
#> 4 Book 2 2022  Author 4
#> 5 Book 3 1845  Author 5
#> 6 Book 3 1845  Author 6
#> 7 Book 3 1845  Author 7
#> 8 Book 3 1845  Author 8


Thanks! I am not very good with lapply - what does the backslash \ in front of (x) do?

\(x)  is short for function(x) .

This will get the class attribute and text into a name-value pair dataset that is output in long format. A book identifier (book) was added to the output data frame to make it easier to do group-by operations (such as pivot to a wide format):
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

book <- html_elements(books, xpath = "//div[@class='book']") 

data <- map_dfr(seq_along(book), \(i) {
  b <- book[[i]]
  children <- html_children(b)
  data.frame(book = i,
             name = children |> html_attrs() |> unlist(use.names = F),
             value = html_text2(children))
})
#    book      name    value
# 1     1 booktitle   Book 1
# 2     1      year     1999
# 3     1    author Author 1
# 4     1    author Author 2
# 5     1    author Author 3
# 6     2 booktitle   Book 2
# 7     2      year     2022
# 8     2    author Author 4
# 9     3 booktitle   Book 3
# 10    3      year     1845
# 11    3    author Author 5
# 12    3    author Author 6
# 13    3    author Author 7
# 14    3    author Author 8

For example,
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(data, id_cols = book, values_fn = toString)
#    book booktitle year  author                             
# 1     1 Book 1    1999  Author 1, Author 2, Author 3          
# 2     2 Book 2    2022  Author 4                              
# 3     3 Book 3    1845  Author 5, Author 6, Author 7, Author 8

